# C#. Проверить содержимое недавно созданных файлов

Tags: c#, алгоритм, ms-word

Возникла необходимость предотвращения создания (или оповещения админа) файлов doc, docx, txt и прочих текстовых документов с конкретной фразой внутри. Предполагаю следующий алгоритм: программа получает текущий список файлов на сетевом диске, заносит их пути в базу, а после (к примеру) каждый час сканирует на наличие новых файлов (сравнивает пути с базой и если путь новый - записывает во вторую базу). Каждый новый файл после этого она проверяет на наличие ключевой фразы (например "тест" при помощи word.interop ) и при наличии этой фразы оповещает админа или удаляет их. Вопрос в следующем: нормальным ли будет этот алгоритм или стоит посмотреть в сторону даты последнего редактирования? Или может у кого есть другие идеи?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь FileSystemWatcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если заморочиться то Вам нужно рыть в сторону подключения виндовских библиотек взаимодействия к шарпу, триггеры и фоновые задания виндовс. Но если заморачиваться не хочется, то с помощью рекурсии проходить по всем файликам, и сохраняете интересующие вас в xml файле. Думаю полного пути файла будет достаточно для проверки. Считаю что база тут не нужна.